# Python program generates TypeError: str object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

I get a type error in one of the lines (Line 26) when trying to print the below result:

```
def myreduce(func, lst):
    x = 0
    x1 = x + 1
    result = lst[x]
    while x1 < len(lst):
        applyfunc = func(result, lst[x1]) #This is the line in question
        result = applyfunc
        x += 1
        x1 += 1
    return round(result, 1)

print(myreduce('`complex`', [3, -1, 4.5, 23, 10]))
```

Comment: Properly formatted code block

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you provide your entire program, as well as the text of the Error you received?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as the first argument to the `myreduce` function.
You are passing a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you call the function.
Instead of:

```py
print(myreduce('`complex`', [3, -1, 4.5, 23, 10]))
```

You must write:

```py
print(myreduce(complex, [3, -1, 4.5, 23, 10]))
```